# Is possible deploy c++ web server on OpenShift3?

Tags: c++, openshift

I am trying to deploy a c++ Http web server on OepnShift3 then I referred [this](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/64-c-web-cartridge).

The problem is:

1. Shall I put the source code on OpenShift or compile it first then put the executable file on OpenShift?
2. Is possible to access the OpenShift3 server via Xshell or Ftp?
3. Any way to get the OepnShift2 account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no longer possible to get accounts on OpenShift 2.

For OpenShift 3, if you wanted to use a custom HTTP server you would need to be able to build a Docker image which includes it and any other files you need. If you can get the Docker image built, then you can deploy it to OpenShift 3.

Although you can get an interactive terminal in the container which runs your application, it doesn't work like traditional web hosting. That is, it isn't a shell access account where you would upload files using FTP or some other means.

Can you explain more about what it is you want to host? Depending on what you are doing there may be builder images already supported by OpenShift which can pull down files from a Git repository and build an image for you.

If OpenShift is new to you, I would suggest you try out:

- https://learn.openshift.com

so you understand some of what it can do and how you interact with it.

Also grab down the free eBook and read it:

- https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html